# Hadoop - master node disk part of the storage cluster suddenly. How do I remove it?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I have 8 slave nodes and 1 master node. Until recently only the slave nodes were part of my HDFS set up. However, recently, the master node popped up on there too with a disk that is much smaller. This is causing problems as that disk got filled fast and the cluster went into safe mode.

I am not sure why or how the master node is now part of the storage. How can I remove it?

I added the master node to the exclude list now. It is decommissioning, but it is taking way too long.

Any thoughts or guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you simply started the `datanode` service on your name node by mistake. I believe you'll have to let the decommission finish for the safest removal.

Comment: Thanks. There was a bunch of issues that culminated in some confusion. Another issue was that the logs drive was full and i couldn't start namenode. fixed that and things seem better. I also restarted the master node. Did not start namenode back up. I had a replication factor of 2. Do i still need to start up datanode again and let it decomission?

Comment: With a replication factor of two, you shouldn't need to let it finish. After some time the name node will assign the under-replicated blocks to new nodes.

Comment: What about all the data in the tmp/dfs folder on the master node... Can I remove it? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I'd wait until the "Number of Under-Replicated Blocks" is 0. That number is in the "Summary" table on the name node's UI. After that, it should be safe to remove.